# How to embed flash SWF with XML in google sites gadget?

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, embed

I am pretty new with AS3 and I´m in dark with an issue.
I made a flash website and want it to run under sites.google.com
The swf file runs fine in any case, not when it´s embedded. The problem is when it runs embedded, as a gadget like google names it, my "playlist.xml" doesn´t load.
I have been searching for an answer along all internet sites and foruns and tutorials, but nothing is working.

### Current Codes are:

XML in fla file is

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(); 
var XML_URL:String = this.loaderInfo.parameters.playlistXML; // -< using flashVars in HTML code 
//var XML_URL:String = "https://sites.google.com/clelsonlopescomposer/playlist.xml"; // <-- used this way too, and relative path like "playlist.xml"; both didn´t work. 
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
 //XML function 
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{ //Place the XML data into XML object         
myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
}
```

Embed code is
HTML Code:

```
<embed src="https://sites.google.com/clelsonlopescomposer/Meusite.swf"
       flashVars="playlistXML=https://sites.google.com/clelsonlopescomposer/playlist.xml"
       allowscriptaccess="always" 
       quality="high" 
       pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1110" height="700">
</embed>
```

I am sure that the problem is in HTML embedding code, but I have no idea how to solve it. Like I said, I´ve been searching for about a week, and my last hope is here.

Thank you very much in advance for your attention and help.
Best Regards,
Clelson

Edit:
Ok. When I run swf file locally in publishing network access only, I get this error when debugging:

> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation:
>   file:///C|/Users/Clelson/Documents/Flash%20Projects/MySite/Meusite.swf
>   cannot load data from
>   https://sites.google.com/site/clelsonlopescomposer/playlist.xml.  at
>   Meusite_fla::list_mc_22/frame10()[Meusite_fla.list_mc_22::frame10:41]

Crossdomain.xml file at https://sites.google.com/crossdomain.xml has the content

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">        
<cross-domain-policy><site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" /></cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a crossdomain-issue. Try adding some error checking or installing the debug flash player and see if anything pops up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonatan, I added and "Edit" in question about crossdomain and errors.